# Can Brussels sprouts be eaten raw?

Tags: brussels-sprouts

I am not sure if this is too lame a question.
Can brussels sprouts be eaten raw, or do I need to boil them for 20 minutes or use some other form of cooking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you mean "Can brussels sprouts be eaten raw?" as in without cooking.  The short answer is yes, though they will be a lot like little cabbages. You don't need to boil them, either.  I like to sauté them in butter in a skillet, then cover them, and let them steam a bit; I serve them with salt and pepper.
Cook them until they are bright green, but not too long to make them grayish green.

Comment: they are not "like" little cabbages, they "ARE" young cabbage buds.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brussels_sprout

Comment: No, they're not young cabbages ... they're not young, and they're not the main head.  They grown with multiple sprouts per plant : http://www.allotment.org.uk/vegetable/brussels-sprouts/index.php

Comment: @Jennifer S Sorry, one more question: do you chop them before to sauté' them in a skillet ? Can I use olive oil as well ?

Comment: I usually cut them in half, or in quarters, depending on size.  It'll be fine with olive oil, too.  I just personally like the taste of them with butter.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, they can be eaten raw, and I do so frequently when they're in season.

I find them much more convenient for sandwich greens and salads when cooking for one than a whole large cabbage; I just chop up what I need (1-2, depending on size), and add 'em to the sandwich, or whatever I might be making.

...and I agree with Jennifer -- don't boil them.  (I like quartering them, and saute in bacon fat 'til they've browned, then a heavy dose of salt.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can eat them raw, but the real question is "how do they taste raw?". The answer to that is that, the taste, well, let's just say it's not the best thing I've ever eaten. How I know this: I'm eating raw brussels sprouts right now!

Answer (score 1):

They can be eaten raw, but they are fairly firm so you'll probably want to either thinly slice them or break them down into separate leaves.

A local sandwich shop thinly slices them on a mandoline, lightly dresses them with mustard seeds and vinegar, and puts them on a pulled-pork sandwich. The result has a much finer texture than typical cole slaw.